What does には means here?
This is from the first chapter of 九頭竜さんの推しは小さい.


ハムスターには珍しく撫でられるのが好き

I think it means something like hamsters like to get petted but I am not sure what's the nuance of には and 珍しく here.

I don't really understand why there's a question here. This には seems perfectly ordinary, and we surely have existing Q&A for the generic use of this combination.

I think this には is always seen together with 珍しく. Xには珍しく means "it is rare for X but" so ハムスターには珍しく撫でられるのが好き means "It is rare for hamsters [to enjoy that] but he likes to get petted."
